# How to cast object type to Task<T> type?

Tags: c#, casting, task

How can I cast an object instance of type `object` to type `Task<T>`?

I store a `Task<T>` reference in a variable of type `object` and need to cast it back to `Task<T>` because the method needs to return type `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `T` is known at the time of casting, there should be no problem doing:

```
Task<T> myTask = (Task<T>)myObject;
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oOg4E8

Comment: I actually had a bug which is why it did not cast correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `Task.FromResult<TResult> method`. From MSDN:

```
T obj = new T();
Task<T> a = Task.FromResult(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `as` operator. If the object is of type `Task<T>` you get a correct references. Otherwise you get `null`.

```
var task = obj as Task<T>;
```

Comment: This is usually a better method than using `(Task<t>)obj`, as you don't have to confirm that it IS a `Task<t>`, you can check for null after the cast.

Answer (score 1):

If the object you have stored is actually the `Task<T>` you can just use a direct cast.

```
var task = (Task<X>)obj;
```

If you have the object result, unwrapped, and you need a task result from the instance, you can use `Task.FromResult(X)` which return a completed `Task<T>` of type `X`.

Comment: `Task.FromResult(x)` does not return a completed `Task<T>`. It returns `Task<object>`. If `Task<T>` is needed then `Task.FromResult<T>(x)` must be used.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

- The variable is defined as `object`
- The value is type `Task<T1>`
- `T1` is not available at compile time.
- You need to cast the object to `Task<T2>` where `T1 : T2`, but not `T1 == T2` (likely `T2` is an interface implemented by `T1`).

The other answers will not work when `T1 != T2`.

This extension method works well for me to preform the cast.

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> CastTask<T>(this object taskObj)
    {
        var taskType = taskObj.GetType();
        if (!taskType.IsSubClassOfGeneric(typeof(Task<>)))
            throw new ArgumentException($"{taskType.FullName} is not of type Task<>");
        var resultType = taskType.GenericTypeArguments.First();
        var castTaskMethodGeneric = typeof(TaskExtensions)
            .GetMethod("CastTaskInner", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var castTaskMethod = castTaskMethodGeneric.MakeGenericMethod(
            new Type[] { resultType, typeof(T) });
        var objCastTask = castTaskMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { taskObj });
        return objCastTask as Task<T>;
    }

    public static async Task<TResult> CastTaskInner<T, TResult>(Task<T> task)
    {
        var t = await task;
        var tObj = (object)t;
        return (TResult)tObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: that was a great solution. I just replaced `IsSubClassOfGeneric` with `taskType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Task<>)` because it looks like a custom extension method that you have. 
One note, I do not have a generic type `T`, So I just called `CastTask` using reflection.